# Primitive type in resource in XAML 2006?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to have a resource of type double, (or strokethickness as a matter of fact). How I can achieve that?

Comment: what have already tried in your attempt to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare a XAML namespace for the `mscorlib` assembly:

```
<Window ... xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    <Window.Resources>
        <sys:Double x:Key="thickness">5</sys:Double>
    </Window.Resources>
    ...
</Window>
```